# error Undefined is not a function appears when switching screens

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Whenever we switch to a new screen on our app it gives an error saying "undefined is not a function (near'...this.setState...')"

```
  state = {
    logInPageDisplay: 'none',
    signUpPageDisplay: 'none',
    homePageDisplay: 'block',
    mapPageDisplay: 'none',
    messagePageDisplay: 'none',
    user: '',
    password: '',
    message: ''
  }
```

```
  handleLogInPagePress = () => {
    this.setState(() => ({
      logInPageDisplay: 'block',
      signUpPageDisplay: 'none',
      homePageDisplay: 'none',
      mapPageDisplay: 'none',
      messagePageDisplay: 'none',
    }));
  }
```

We attempted to import set state, and removed this, but to no prevail, the screen swapping failed.

Comment: Please share a little more code... How are you defining `state` and `setState`? I am assuming you're using a Class component because you have used the `this` keyword, however the you may be missing `this` from `this.state = {...` (the state declaration)

Comment: Here is the link to our code, https://replit.com/@mobile-apps1/React-Native-Personal-Project-mobile-apps1#App.js, we are not using class components and are trying to do function but appear to not know enough to translate it all.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code, the link does not work for me